# How can I restrict this dataclass serialization to only attributes on the base class?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Here's some code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Foo:
    f: str

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Baz(Foo):
    b: str

    def full(self):
        return self.to_dict()
        # as expected, returns {"f":"f", "b":"b"}


    def partial(self):
        return Foo.to_dict(self)
        # also returns {"f":"f", "b":"b"}
        # how can I make it just return {"f":"f"}?


print(Baz(f="f", b="b").partial())
```

output:

```json
{"f":"f"}
```

How can I restrict the value returned by `partial` to only `f` and not both `b` and `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Foo` classes schema to only output fields that exist on `Foo`

```
    def partial(self):
        return Foo.schema().dump(self)
```